# Obtener el value de un input button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, web, razor

Tengo unos botones creados dinamicamente, y deseo que al hacer click sobre ellos obtenga su `value` para poder interactuar con el.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < pagesMax; i++)
{
    <input type="button" value=@(i+1) class="bottom" id="id" />
}
```

Estuve probando con algo así pero no me funcionó:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#id").click(function () {
                alert($("#id").attr("value"));
            });

        });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En vez de `id,` asignale `class`. `id` solo se utiliza cuando tienes identificar 1 solo elemento, `class` cuando quieres identificar varios:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < pagesMax; i++)
{
    <input type="button" value=@(i+1) class="bottom mi-input" />
}

@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".mi-input").click(function () {
                alert(this.value);
            });

        });

    </script>
}
```

Nota como se utiliza `this.value` dentro del evento. Esto para obtener la referencia del elemento que se esta dando click.

Answer (score 0):

Estás poniéndole a todos los botones el mismo ***id*** por lo que a la hora de capturar el value se pierde porque hay varios controles con el mismo id. Prueba tratando de diferenciar el id de los botones `id="id+i`"

Comment: si me imagine lo de los id, probe como dices y nada. sino podria ser cambiando el input por button. La verdad no se me ocurre como crearlos dinamicamente para poder usar sus value al momente del click.